# HTMLとPHPタグを合わせて記述する際のコーディングルール(インデント及び改行)について

Tags: php, coding-style

HTMLとPHPタグを合わせて記述する際のコーディングルール(インデント及び改行)について、参考になりそうなものを探しています。好きに書けば良いとは思いますが、この辺りについて言及しているページはありますか？

案a
・phpタグの後、改行しない
・phpが連続している場合も、phpタグを書く

```
<?php if($japan): ?>  
  <header><?php echo $language; ?></header>
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php if($america): ?>
  <?php $language = str_replace('こんにちは', 'hello', $language); ?>
  <header><?php echo $language; ?></header>
<?php endif; ?>
```

案a2
・phpタグの後、改行しない
・phpが連続している場合は、なるべくphpタグを書かない

```
<?php if($japan): ?>  
  <header><?php echo $language; ?></header>
<?php endif; 
if($america):
  $language = str_replace('こんにちは', 'hello', $language); ?>
  <header><?php echo $language; ?></header>
<?php endif; ?>
```

案b
・phpタグの後、改行するが半角空けない

```
<?php
if($japan):
?>  
  <header>
    <?php
    echo $language;
    ?>
  </header>
<?php
endif;
?> 
<?php
if($america):
?>
  <?php $language = str_replace('こんにちは', 'hello', $language); ?>
  <header>
    <?php
    echo $language;
    ?>
  </header>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

案b2
・条件分岐phpタグの後、改行するが半角空けない

```
<?php
if($japan):
?>  
  <header><?php echo $language; ?></header>
<?php
endif;
?> 
<?php
if($america):
?>
  <?php $language = str_replace('こんにちは', 'hello', $language); ?>
  <header><?php echo $language; ?></header>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

案c
・phpタグの後、改行して半角空ける

```
<?php
  if($japan):
?>  
  <header>
    <?php
      echo $language;
    ?>
  </header>
<?php
  endif;
?> 
<?php
  if($america):
?>
  <?php
    $language = str_replace('こんにちは', 'hello', $language);
  ?>
  <header>
    <?php
      echo $language;
    ?>
  </header>
<?php
  endif;
?>
```

案c2
・条件分岐phpタグの後のみ、改行して半角空ける

```
<?php
  if($japan):
?>  
  <header><?php echo $language; ?></header>
<?php
  endif;
?> 
<?php
  if($america):
?>
  <?php $language = str_replace('こんにちは', 'hello', $language); ?>
  <header><?php echo $language; ?></header>
<?php
  endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

こんにちは、特にPSRに記述のない事柄なのでスクリプトとして認識されれば自由な記法で問題ないと思います。細かいことを言うと ifの直後と条件式の後には空白をひとついれます。`if (hoge) {`のように。

http://www.infiniteloop.co.jp/docs/psr/psr-2-coding-style-guide.html

公式のドキュメントでは案aの記法になっているようです。

https://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

以下は個人の見解となります

- ショートハンド記法を利用して`endif;`で閉じるよりは、波ブラケット'{'を使って記述したほうがいいと思いました(他にPHPスクリプトがある場合整合性がとれるため作業者の負担が減る)
- やむを得ない理由がないのであれば、なんらかのフレームワークかテンプレートエンジンを採用して、PHPをHTML中に埋め込む形は避けた方が、見通しもよくなりセキュアになります。素のPHPでスクリプトの無害化は困難です。

Comment: 「ifの直後と条件式の後には空白をひとついれます」PSR-2で規定されているのですね。初めて知りました。今度から取り入れていこうと思いました。「PHPをHTML中に埋め込む形は避けた方が」フレームワークのVではどうしても埋め込む形になると思うのですが…

Comment: PHPでは素のPHPをテンプレートに使うケースも多いようですね。僕の環境ではJavaフレームワークの影響からだいたいはSmartyをビューとして導入していました。文字のエスケープや無害化などセキュリティの確保上有利だからです。ここらへんは議論の余地があると思います。